# Removing Choice Column Data Generated by User Through Infopath Form

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, choice-field

I created a list with a choice column. Let's call this list List A. I modified the form through InfoPath and set it up so that the choice options are connected to another SharePoint list (List B). Changing list items in List B updated the choice column options in List A.

Now the problem is that as the choice column options are updated via List B, previously checked off options in List A that are not in List B anymore are still visible. I'd like them to disappear as List B is changed as that data in List A is irrelevant at that point. I am mainly afraid that I could run into size limit issues with dozens of checked off choice items and growing without an easy way to purge the data.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using OOB Lookup column to get the information from List B in List A. Lookup column can also get the options from another list and user can select the relevant options.

Lookup column in List A will automatically update if there is any update for column in List B.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much. You saved me hours of fiddling with the options. And I was able to keep my InfoPath form!

Comment: I'm glad the reply helps you, you can mark it as answer. Thanks for your understanding.